# Fast ways to join multiple huge parquet tables to huge parquet table

Tags: python, apache-spark, join, parquet

I have a parquet table - let's call it `table_a` - that is about 6 GB. I need to join this table with half a million other parquet tables, say, `table_1`...`table_n`, which range in size between 10 MB and 20 GB. I then write the contents of the join out somewhere else. The join fields are A, B, and C, and the suffixes on the table names (1...n) denote that table's value for A.

This runs very quickly (< 1 min) if I choose one table, say table_1, then filter table_a down to only records where 'A' == '1', and then do a join:

```
table_1 = sqlContext.read.load(path_to_table_1)
table_a = sqlContext.read.load(path_to_table_a).filter("A = '1'")
broadcasted_a = broadcast(table_a)
# omitting "A" here because we've already filtered down for it
result = table_1.join(broadcasted_a, ["B", "C"))
do_something_with_result(result)
```

However, when I try to do a join without pre-filtering table_a, the join hangs. I've waited for 10-20 minutes for the join to complete but haven't seen it finish. So, although I can get this to work for 1 table with filtering, I'm not sure how to do this across all tables 1...n. I could loop over the half-million parquet tables and follow the above procedure for each, but I wonder if there is a faster way to express those joins and to loop over the parquet tables in parallel. One thought I had was to collect the paths for tables 1...n into an rdd and then try:

```
table_a = sqlContext.read.load(path_to_table_a)

def my_function(path):
    # The paths are formatted such that the suffix of each path is the table's value for column A
    filter_key = path.split('=')[-1]
    table = sqlContext.read.load(path)
    table_a_filtered = table_a.filter("A = '%s'" % filter_key)
    result = table.join(table_a_filtered, ["B", "C"])
    do_something_with_result(result)

path_rdd = sc.parallelize(table_paths)
path_rdd.foreach(my_function)
```

But this doesn't work because you can't nest rdds within functions such as `foreach`.

What are my options for joining these tables quickly? Is there some other way I can do filtering for each table 1...n without nesting rdds? Or is there some way to optimize a single, massive join between all tables 1...n and table_a?

**Update 1**

I re-ran a join of table_1 with table_a (without pre-filtering), and eventually I got the following warnings, after which all the jobs crashed:

```
2017-06-01 14:49:11,879 WARN          org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient  - 
Error Recovery for block XXX in pipeline DatanodeInfoWithStorage[XXX,DISK], 
DatanodeInfoWithStorage[XXX,DISK], 
DatanodeInfoWithStorage[XXX,DISK]: bad datanode DatanodeInfoWithStorage[XXX,DISK]
```

I then tried removing the broadcast of table_a, and then doing the join (again, without pre-filtering) -- it worked perfectly. So next, I'm going to try to read in the entire directory of parquet tables and join the resulting DataFrame against the table_a DataFrame - but I'm open to any other, more efficient solutions.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve isn't very clear. What's the purpose of joining on a list of filtered keys like that...

Comment: My end goal is to do a join. It doesn't have to be done by filtering first. The only reason I mentioned filtering is that for one table, it's significantly faster to filter first and then do a join, so I was thinking that maybe there is a way to do that across all the tables. But maybe that isn't the case -- either way, just brainstorming.

Comment: so to make it simple, you just want to do something like df.join(df2,Seq("...") ?

Comment: Yes - this is what I'm going to try next (see update), but I'm worried about efficiency, so open to any optimization suggestions.

Comment: The Catalyzer will optimize that for you. You don't need to optimize